# Is Capped Collection available in Orientdb?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, orientdb

I need to save my data which can have large amount of insertions, retrievals and deletions I was looking up for mysql but when i read the article about Mongodb it can handle these kind of transactions so just wanted to compare mysql vs capped collection and also is capped collection available in orientdb?

Comment: What kind of data-structure are you gonna use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrientDB doesn't support capped collections, but you could implement it by using a hook with a callback onAfterCreate() checks the size and delete the first record.